# wrapper height not responding to grid row content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm going to try and give as much detail as possible, I tried everything, nothing seems like it answers my questions when searching through these forums.

I have a grid layout and a wrapper for the content outside of the grid layout, it's wrapping everything but the header and footer.

When I add content into the rows it expands vertically, however, the wrapper seems to be static in height, it causes overflow of the grid and it covers the footer and moves it around.

I tried playing with the grid height, the wrapper height, display, viewport height, any to no avail. I'm trying to keep the grid inside of the wrapper and leave the header and footer at the top and bottom so when I scroll down it can look like a single-page website.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* reset the browser to remove any wierd spacing & remove decoration on all links */

body{

}
/* body tag can be used to add image background or color */

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li a {
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        border: 1px solid grey;
}
/* wrapper that content inside is lined up on the left and right side of the website values go clockwise from top */

.content {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(minmax(5%, min-content) 234px 234px 234px minmax(5%, min-content));
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
                         ". headline socialmedia sidebar ."
                         ". portfolio portfolio sidebar ."
                         ". about about sidebar ."
                         ". resume resume sidebar .";
}
/* adding display grid turns the immediate children of the parent div become grid items */
/* display grid will define the grid, 1fr will create 1 column */
/* the . in the template areas also create a wrapper effect with white space */

.content div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: gold;
}

.content div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: grey;
}

#header {
    grid-area: header;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}

#headline {
    grid-area: headline;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#socialmedia {
    grid-area: socialmedia;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 15px;
}

#portfolio {
    grid-area: portfolio;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#about {
    grid-area: about;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#resume {
    grid-area: resume;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#footer {
    text-align: left;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

#footer-left {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#footer-right {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

/* position footer bottom with bottom 0 */

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
/* below this line is code for small screens */

#header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
/* align-items aligns content inside header on same horizontal axis */
/* justify-content creates space between content inside header */


ul {
    display: none;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: ;
}

svg {
    float: right;   
}

.wrapper {
    width: 414px;
    height
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: grid;
}

.content {
    !important;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
                         "headline"
                         "portfolio"
                         "about"
                         "resume"
                         "socialmedia";                      
}

#footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    positon: sticky;
}

}
```

```html
    <body>

            <div id="header">

                <img src="Logo1.png" width="100" height="100"><br>
                    
                <nav>   
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/></svg>
                    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">RESUME</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </nav>

            </div>

                <div class="wrapper">

                    <div class="content">
                        <div id="headline"><h3>Headline</h3> </div>
                        <div id="sidebar"><h3>Sidebar</h3></div>
                        <div id="socialmedia"><h3>Socialmedia</h3> <br>
                        <?xml version="1.0" ?><svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="40" width="40"><title/><path d="M256,0C114.615,0,0,114.615,0,256S114.615,512,256,512,512,397.385,512,256,397.385,0,256,0Zm90.526,162.743-53.366,102.3,4,5.744h49.122v73.16H257.469l-8.262,5.352-22.185,42.526a41.5,41.5,0,0,1-7.45,10.153l-.688.688H165.475v-53.41l53.366-102.3-4-5.744H165.717V168.051h88.815l8.262-5.351,22.184-42.527a41.5,41.5,0,0,1,7.451-10.153l.687-.687h53.41Z"/></svg>

                            <?xml version="1.0" ?><svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="40" width="40"><title/><path d="M191.32,267.878h-46.3v50.687h46.3a25.344,25.344,0,1,0,0-50.687Z"/><path d="M212.622,212.989A23.924,23.924,0,0,0,188.7,189.064l-.1-.055-.022.055H145.023v47.85H188.7A23.925,23.925,0,0,0,212.622,212.989Z"/><path d="M334.578,240.281a30.557,30.557,0,0,0-30.339,26.928h60.679A30.557,30.557,0,0,0,334.578,240.281Z"/><path d="M256,0C114.615,0,0,114.615,0,256S114.615,512,256,512,512,397.385,512,256,397.385,0,256,0ZM203.344,349.528h-94.8V158.1h91.9a48.7,48.7,0,0,1,22.265,92.007,51.6,51.6,0,0,1-19.368,99.42Zm84.3-180.255h92.87v22.8h-92.87ZM400.986,292.137H304.542q-.022.612-.023,1.229a31.517,31.517,0,0,0,58.73,15.9l.064.037h36.85c-9.006,30.666-35.887,44.447-65.2,44.447-38.812,0-67.687-32.007-67.687-71.489s28.875-71.489,67.687-71.489S407.876,244.105,400.986,292.137Z"/></svg>

                            <?xml version="1.0" ?><svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="40" width="40"><title/><path d="M256,0C114.615,0,0,114.615,0,256S114.615,512,256,512,512,397.385,512,256,397.385,0,256,0ZM183.435,382.667H126.381V203.653h57.054ZM154.908,180.208a32.1,32.1,0,1,1,32.1-32.1A32.1,32.1,0,0,1,154.908,180.208ZM389.2,382.667h-56l0-97.882c0-4.973.785-37.949-27.219-37.949a30.948,30.948,0,0,0-25.681,12.576,39.134,39.134,0,0,0-7.818,23.8v99.451H216.55V203.653h53.216v25.124c12.737-19.541,28.789-26.694,44.578-29.573,28.027-5.11,74.851,11.952,74.851,62.9Z"/></svg>
                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolio"><h3>Portfolio</h3></div>
                        <div id="about"><h3>About</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a congue ligula, quis tempor justo. Maecenas arcu arcu, blandit quis elit et, fringilla fermentum sem. Morbi aliquam gravida rhoncus. Integer et tristique sapien, quis pharetra arcu. Sed vel consequat ex, commodo aliquet metus. Duis justo lectus, feugiat sed est ac, faucibus sollicitudin lacus. Aliquam vehicula diam non arcu malesuada, vel dapibus diam volutpat. Sed vehicula et mi vitae facilisis. Nam gravida est eu massa ultrices, a venenatis lectus consectetur. Sed vestibulum commodo sem sit amet iaculis.</div>
                        <div id="resume"><h3>Resume</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a congue ligula, quis tempor justo. Maecenas arcu arcu, blandit quis elit et, fringilla fermentum sem. Morbi aliquam gravida rhoncus. Integer et tristique sapien, quis pharetra arcu. Sed vel consequat ex, commodo aliquet metus. Duis justo lectus, feugiat sed est ac, faucibus sollicitudin lacus. Aliquam vehicula diam non arcu malesuada, vel dapibus diam volutpat. Sed vehicula et mi vitae facilisis. Nam gravida est eu massa ultrices, a venenatis lectus consectetur. Sed vestibulum commodo sem sit amet iaculis.</div>
                    </div>

                </div>  

                        <div id="footer">

                            <div id="footer-left">
                                <ul>
                                    <li style="display: block;"><a href="#header">header</a>
                                    <li style="display: block;"><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
                                    <li style="display: block;"><a href="#about">about</a>
                                    <li style="display: block;"><a href="#resume">resume</a>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div id="footer-right">
                                <?xml version="1.0" ?><svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20"><title/><path d="M256,0C114.615,0,0,114.615,0,256S114.615,512,256,512,512,397.385,512,256,397.385,0,256,0Zm90.526,162.743-53.366,102.3,4,5.744h49.122v73.16H257.469l-8.262,5.352-22.185,42.526a41.5,41.5,0,0,1-7.45,10.153l-.688.688H165.475v-53.41l53.366-102.3-4-5.744H165.717V168.051h88.815l8.262-5.351,22.184-42.527a41.5,41.5,0,0,1,7.451-10.153l.687-.687h53.41Z"/></svg>

                                <?xml version="1.0" ?><svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20"><title/><path d="M191.32,267.878h-46.3v50.687h46.3a25.344,25.344,0,1,0,0-50.687Z"/><path d="M212.622,212.989A23.924,23.924,0,0,0,188.7,189.064l-.1-.055-.022.055H145.023v47.85H188.7A23.925,23.925,0,0,0,212.622,212.989Z"/><path d="M334.578,240.281a30.557,30.557,0,0,0-30.339,26.928h60.679A30.557,30.557,0,0,0,334.578,240.281Z"/><path d="M256,0C114.615,0,0,114.615,0,256S114.615,512,256,512,512,397.385,512,256,397.385,0,256,0ZM203.344,349.528h-94.8V158.1h91.9a48.7,48.7,0,0,1,22.265,92.007,51.6,51.6,0,0,1-19.368,99.42Zm84.3-180.255h92.87v22.8h-92.87ZM400.986,292.137H304.542q-.022.612-.023,1.229a31.517,31.517,0,0,0,58.73,15.9l.064.037h36.85c-9.006,30.666-35.887,44.447-65.2,44.447-38.812,0-67.687-32.007-67.687-71.489s28.875-71.489,67.687-71.489S407.876,244.105,400.986,292.137Z"/></svg>

                                <?xml version="1.0" ?><svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20"><title/><path d="M256,0C114.615,0,0,114.615,0,256S114.615,512,256,512,512,397.385,512,256,397.385,0,256,0ZM183.435,382.667H126.381V203.653h57.054ZM154.908,180.208a32.1,32.1,0,1,1,32.1-32.1A32.1,32.1,0,0,1,154.908,180.208ZM389.2,382.667h-56l0-97.882c0-4.973.785-37.949-27.219-37.949a30.948,30.948,0,0,0-25.681,12.576,39.134,39.134,0,0,0-7.818,23.8v99.451H216.55V203.653h53.216v25.124c12.737-19.541,28.789-26.694,44.578-29.573,28.027-5.11,74.851,11.952,74.851,62.9Z"/></svg>
    
                                    <hr style="width:15%; padding-bottom:10px;">
<!-- hr rule width can cause problems with float if it's too large -->
                                        <p>© All Rights Reserved.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>  

        </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I finally got it to work.
I made a couple of changes.

1. I changed to grid layout and added . to each side of the grid area for spacing(Basically tried to match the content grid as I did the full screen as similarly as possible).
2. I added overflow: hidden to the wrapper, which oddly didn't work the first time, maybe because my code was messed up.
3. I deleted an extra /div tag I had in my HTML.
4. I removed the padding in my footer (don't even know if that had much to do with anything, it might not have done a thing).
5. Removed the sidebar by adding display: none.